# Slow performance when storing handle objects in a cell array

Tags: arrays, performance, oop, matlab

I have massive **performance** problems with just a very little portion of my **MATLAB Code** an hope you might have an idea how to improve it:

I am developing an agent based simulation in MATLAB that creates **lots of handle objects**. Some of them are agents others can be e.g. objects that are owned by the agents.

To clearly identify each of these handle object **every single one gets a unique Id** (obj.Id) that is issued by an "*IdDistributor*" object. The *IdDistributor* itself is handed over to the constructor of each object that is to resive an Id and is called from there to give out an Id-number (*giveId*).

In addition the *IdDistributor* keeps a sort of **phone book (an *IdRegistry*) that associates each Id with the object**. So given the Id one can look up the object in the *IdRegistry*.

I implemented this by using a **cell array that stores the different handle objects in exactly that field that matches their Id**. (Normal array does not work since the objects are of different classes).

Testing my simulation it is really slow and the MATLAB *Profiler* shows that 99% of the time is spent with the *IdDistributor* especially with the line that stores the objects in the *IdRegistry* (It took something like 1 seconds per object when I tried to create about 10,000 objects).

Now I'm trying to come to a similar **solution that takes less time**. As you can see in the code below I have already tried to increase Speed with pre-allocation (I extend the *IdRegistry* by 10,000 cells when it is full, instead of sizing up 1 by 1).I also thought about trying to somehow get the MATLAB internal Id of the handle objects but didn't follow that road when I read that that Id is not permanent and can be changed by the system.

**I would really much appreciate any ideas either how to speed up the code or to find a workaround/improvement to my concept!**

**Here my Code:**

The slowest line is *IdDist.IdRegistry(IdNumber)={obj};*

btw. changing it to *IdDist.IdRegistry{IdNumber}=obj;* didn't help much

```
classdef IdDistributor < handle

properties
    Id=int64(1); %Her own ID
    LastId=int64(1);
    IdRegistry={}
end

methods
    function IdDist=IdDistributor()
        IdDist.Id=int64(1);
        IdDist.LastId=int64(1);
        IdDist.register(IdDist);
    end
    function IdNum=giveId(IdDist,obj)
        IdNum=IdDist.LastId+int64(1);
        IdDist.LastId=IdNum;
        IdDist.register(obj,IdNum)
    end
    function register(IdDist,obj,IdNum)
        if nargin==2      
            IdNumber=obj.Id;
        elseif nargin==3
            IdNumber=IdNum;
        end
            if IdNumber>=length(IdDist.IdRegistry) %Extend the Register by 10000
              IdDist.IdRegistry(IdNumber+10000)={[]};    
            end
            if IdNumber >0
              IdDist.IdRegistry(IdNumber)={obj};
            end
    end %function
    end %methods
    end %class
```

Comment: I have now tried to change the pre-allocation to: _IdDist.IdRegistry(IdNumber+10000)={SomeDummyHandleObject};_ because a friend suggested that the size of the cell might change from an empty cell {[]} to when a handle object reference is stored and might cause Matlab to reallocate memory. However, this saved only 0.009 sec out of 1.428 sec selftime in _IdDistributor.register_.

Comment: What is you memory consumption like when running 'slow'?
Is it possible you are making copies of the objects instead of just storing handles?

Comment: As they are all Matlab handle objects I would be surprised if they were/could be copied. I have however, just made a major improvement by changing the Type of IdRegistry from _Cell_ to _Map_. I was just going to post my solution but stackoverflow forces me to wait for 8h since I'm new. Here in short: Change in the property section: IdRegistry=containers.Map('KeyType','int64','ValueType','any') ; Took out pre-allocation block; change in registration to: IdDist.IdRegistry(IdNumber)=obj; ; TAKES NOW ONLY 17% of the time. Don't know why. Full Answer in a few hours.

Comment: Even though they are handle objects (and imo shouldn't be copied), I tried to check the Memory but find it hard to do, since the objects are created around the time they are registered (which is part of their construction).

Comment: While yesterday I thought I managed to speed up the code by a factor of 5 using a **Map** (ran a Test with 400 Objects) - I ran a test with 10.000 Objects overnight and **it is not faster than the original with cells**. So I am puzzled again. I will let you know if I find something new and would be thankful for any further suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not deleting objects from your registry, you might like to try deriving all your objects from the [matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneousclass.html) class, then storing them as a regular array. Note that this will require R2011a or newer.

I don't know if this is faster, but it's something to try. Of course it'll only be useful if all your IDs are generated by the IdDistributor, since they're sequential.

Also, my tests suggest that

```
length(IdDist.IdRegistry)
```

is also slow, so you could store the length of the registry in the `IdDistributor` as well. and I would suggest setting the `SetAccess` to `protected` for the properties, for safety.

Comment: True length(IdDist.IdRegistry) takes some time. I'll try minin.Heterogenous when I updated my program version.

Answer (score 0):

I have further looked into the issue and it appears to me that actually most time is lost in the process of calling the giveId method of the IdDistributer from a different object and not so much inside the method.

I have also identified other places in my program where similar problems occur. Especially when many handle objects are constructed and stored in an array and this array is stored as the property of an object. So the original cause of the slow performance might lie in this as the IdDistributer is usually used when new handle objects are created.

Since this is a somewhat different topic I posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726487/how-to-avoid-matlab-taking-exponential-time-when-creating-a-handle-object-array-a) including some simple code for illustration.

Comment: There are actually some related answers to this question under my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726487/how-to-avoid-matlab-taking-exponential-time-when-creating-a-handle-object-array-a/7727501#7727501) outlined above. They might be helpful if many objects of the same class are to be stored at once in the property of another object.